# Android How to synchronize a Layout view?

Tags: android, scrollview, synchronized

I have a *TableLayout*, within a *ScrollView*, which is updated constantly by an *AsyncTask*.

I don't know if it is "legal" to **add/remove rows** by the *AsyncTask* when at the same time the user may be scrolling the TableLayout.

How can I make sure the update does not interfere with the Scrolling in the GUI?

Or does the OS take care of this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, the main thread that your Application runs on is the only thread that can update the UI.  If you try to modify the contents of your layout from within an AsyncTask, you'll get an error.  AsyncTask's `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods, however, ARE run on the main thread, so you can update the UI there.

So, to answer your question, yes the OS takes care of this for you by not allowing asynchronous UI updates.

Comment: What about onProgressUpdate()? It also runs on the main thread, doesn't it? Will it be OK to add Rows there? If yes, do I need to synchronize it or just add the Row normally?

Comment: `onProgressUpdate()` does also run on the main thread.  It is totally fine to add or remove rows in that method.  However, the user will be able to interact with your app while this is happening, so they'll probably notice the rows being added and deleted if they are viewing the list.  So long as they're just looking at the items, this will be fine.  You may run into some weird situations if the rows have click listeners, but I've never tried what you're describing so I don't know for sure.

Comment: One more thing, it's important to note that if you allow the user to switch Activities while the AsyncTask is running, it will continue in the background.  The Activity will not be destroyed or garbage collected until it's done, and your task will essentially be taking up cycles doing nothing.  This shouldn't cause your app to crash directly, as all the UI components and class variables are kept in memory until destroyed, but could lead to issues such as an OOM error later on, or, depending on the Android version running, block future AsyncTask from running because the thread is being used.